# Training a ML model using features of type string and int

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm building a recommendation model using data which consist of 
UserID, X, Y and Z, where X is the service line, Y is his Expertise and Z is his Rank.

My training set consists of data which contains a group of words for each of these `UserIDs` they further consist of `difficulty_level(int)` and `duration(int)`.
The training set is history of the users who have used the service earlier.

How should I deal with the text data? Also how should further design the model?

I tried to design the model using different text pre processing techniques using Keras but I cannot seem to get how I should train my model using such training data?

Comment: Please show work you have attempted and where failures occurred. Also review methods for content based recommendation systems if you want to use text as a recommendation feature.

Comment: You can tokenize the text and pad it to a fixed length. Then, you will have integer arrays which have equal lengths. See [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/prepare-text-data-deep-learning-keras/)